# PHP creates super large image file

Tags: php, image, gd, large-data

In my app users uploads multiple photos (e.g. 3000x2000 each, in JPG and PNG formats). My PHP program needs to layout those photos and combine them into 1 large photos.

For example, a user uploads 4 photos - p1.jpg, p2.jpg, p3.jpg, p4.jpg, and each is 3000x2000. I need to create a large image that places the 4 images in a 2x2 grid layout like this -

```
+-----+-----+  (overall witdh = 6000, overall height = 4000)
| p1  | p2  |
+-----+-----+
| p3  | p4  |
+-----+-----+
```

I can make each image smaller (e.g. 50% of original) so that the overall size can be shrunk down, but if user uploads 8 images or 16 images, the overall size will become super large again.

The resulting image will consume very high memory in PHP, so my question is, what's the best way to create that large image with minimum memory consumption.

One idea I have is that we use a stream to handle large data files chunk by chunk. So I wonder if there is a solution/library allowing chunk-by-chunk image merging.

Comment: A job queue would be a good ideea for such memory consuming processes...now depends on your app's tech stack

Comment: I would accept the fact that it'll use lots of memory, create a background worker that accepts image conversion jobs from a queue and reserve a big enough server to run a predetermined number of those workers on, so you have some amount of control over how much memory will be used by them. The last thing you'll want to do is run this kind of task in a web server thread, much less many of them uncontrolled in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest that instead of uploading one big image you can upload all the images independently but while displaying or while downloading you can write some script which will convert all uploaded images into your one big image layout.

If you have some specific position for the image then you can use canvas library called http://fabricjs.com/. By using this library you can customize your image and you can save all the image position in your database and later you can fetch images according to that position.